# AttachEvent of 0 is undefined

Tags: javascript, debugging, attachevent

I want to automatically resize parts of my Website with the onchange-Event. But as always I got a little problem to solve.
Console gives this error:

`The property undefined or a null reference can not be retrieved`".

```
function Resize() {
    var winHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var startElements = document.getElementsByClassName('start');
    for (var i = 1; i <= startElements.length; i++) {
        document.startElements[i].attachEvent('onchange', function StartResize() {
        startElements[i].style.paddingLeft = winWidth * 0.1;
        startElements[i].style.paddingRight = winWidth * 0.1;
        });
    };
};

<body onload="Resize">
```

Last Thing. I already wrote the script-tag in my html document at the end of the body-tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `document` from `document.startElements`.

You are probably looking for `Resize()`. You forgot the `()` to invoke your function.

```
<body onload="Resize()">
```

However, inline JS (like onload in your html) has never been a good practice. Check out some of these results: **[Why is inline JS bad?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)**

Instead, you should attach the event listener with JavaScript like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  //code here
});
```

Unless you want your code to only work in IE5-8, you need to use `addEventListener` not `attachEvent`, so that should be `addEventListener('change',`

I also wonder if you meant to start your loop on `1` rather than `0`. The first element will be item `0`. If you only have one item on the page, you are skipping it and starting with an item that doesn't exist.

So, also try:

```
for (var i = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise! I just forgot to invoke it in my question in my code i did, sry for the mistake. But what i am really looking for is a mistake with the .getElementsByClassName(''). I think it doesnt work with the Eventlistener

Comment: @user3237742 one more update I added - you probably meant to start your loop with `i=0` not `i=1`. I updated my answer again.

Comment: Oh i solved it by myself :D
i wrote document.startElements[i].addEventListener(...
but it should be like this:
startElements[i].addEventListener(...